# How to return JSON data from servlet and get that from the success call back function of ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets

I am trying to return JSON data from servlet and access that data from the success call back function of ajax call.
Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#submit").on("click", function()
    {
        userId = $("#userNameTxt").val();
        seqAns = $("#seqAnsTxt").val();
        seqQues = $("#seqQues").val();
        command = $("#_CMD").val()
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "/Inventory/InvController",
            data : {_CMD : command, uid : userId, ques : seqQues, ans : seqAns},
            success : function(retVal)
            {
                if(true)
                {
                    $("#resetPwd").show();
                }
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my Serrvlet Code:

```
boolean isSuccess = logHelper.performForgotPwdValidation(agentDetails);
    PrintWriter out = null;
    JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
    try 
    {
        jsonObj.addProperty("isValid", isSuccess);
        response.setContentType( "application/json" );
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(jsonObj.toString());
        out.flush();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if( null != out )
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to return "isSuccess" as a Json data. How should I return that. Please let me also know how to get that return data in the success call back function of ajax call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: With the above code snippet every time call is going to the error call back function. But if I remove dataType : "json" from my ajax call and change response.setContentType( "application/json" ); to response.setContentType( "text/plain" ), then it is going to the success call back function. It seems JSON data is not formed properly in servlet.@charlietfl

Comment: Suggest you update question then to reflect the actual problem